# Dividir string em substrings e procurá-las em outra

Tags: sql-server

Estou a criar uma função na qual eu verificarei se um `endereço_A` contém partes em um `endereço_B`, exemplificando:

**endereço_A**

`AVENIDA JOÃO E MARIA`

**endereço_B**

`RUA JOÃO`

O resultado deve retornar `JOÃO`, que é a substring que ambos os endereços possuem em comum.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitSearchAddress ( @addressSearch VARCHAR(MAX), @addressIn VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
    @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @pos INT
    DECLARE @separator CHAR(1)

    SET @separator = ' '

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@separator, @addressSearch) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@separator, @addressSearch)  
        SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@addressSearch, 1, @pos-1)

        IF CHARINDEX(@name, @addressIn) > 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @returnList 
            SELECT @name

        END

        SELECT @addressSearch = SUBSTRING(@addressSearch, @pos+1, LEN(@addressSearch)-@pos)

    END

    INSERT INTO @returnList
    SELECT ISNULL(@addressSearch, 0)

    RETURN
END
```

O problema dá-se quando eu procuro algo que não contém no `endereço_B` e ele me retorna o último valor mesmo não sendo encontrado,. Qual seria a forma ideal para solucionar isso? Será preciso ficar redefinindo a variável para cada condição mesmo?

Exemplo do Problema:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitSearchAddress('RUA JOÃO E MARIA', 'AVENIDA JOÃO')
```

Ele me retornará

```
JOÃO
E
MARIA
```

Quando deveria retornar somente

```
JOÃO
```

Se a substring do `endereço_A` é a última posição e se for localizada no `endereço_B`, funciona corretamente:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitSearchAddress('RUA MARIA JOÃO', 'AVENIDA JOÃO')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `CHARINDEX` não funciona pro seu problema, pois ele procura ocorrências na String. Palavras como "Rua Da", "RUA A" iriam cair na mesma situação que a palavra "E".

Quando "E" é atribuida há variável `@name` o `IF CHARINDEX('E', 'AVENIDA JOÃO')` é retornado 3 devido a ocorrência de "E" em "AVENIDA".

Uma solução que encontrei foi quebrar o texto "RUA JOÃO E MARIA" e "AVENIDA JOÃO" em tabelas distintas usando uma função `Split(' ')` com delimitador espaço, após isso você pode compara o que há de comum usando um `INNER JOIN`. Meu código ficou assim.

**Funcão Split :**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] ( @text VARCHAR(MAX),
                                      @delimiter VARCHAR(20) = ' ' ) RETURNS @Strings TABLE ( [position] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                                                                                                                              [value] VARCHAR(100) ) AS BEGIN DECLARE @index INT
SET @index = -1 WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0) BEGIN -- Find the first delimiter

SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @text) IF (@index = 0)
AND (LEN(@text) > 0) BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Strings
VALUES (CAST(@text AS VARCHAR(100))) BREAK END

                IF (@index > 1) BEGIN
INSERT INTO @Strings
VALUES (CAST(LEFT(@text, @index - 1) AS VARCHAR(100)))
SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) END --Delimiter is 1st position = no @text to insert
 ELSE
SET @text = CAST(RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) AS VARCHAR(100)) END RETURN END
```

**Função splitSearchAddress:**(adaptada)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitSearchAddress (@addressSearch VARCHAR(MAX), @addressIn VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500)) AS BEGIN DECLARE @Temp1 TABLE (NAME varchar(MAX)) DECLARE @Temp2 TABLE (NAME varchar(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Temp1
SELECT value
FROM dbo.Split(@addressSearch, ' ');


INSERT INTO @Temp2
SELECT value
FROM dbo.Split(@addressIn, ' ');


INSERT INTO @returnList
SELECT T1.NAME
FROM @Temp1 T1
    INNER JOIN @Temp2 T2 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME RETURN 
END
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitSearchAddress('RUA JOÃO E MARIA', 'AVENIDA JOÃO')
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tomando como base uma função para separar as palavras por espaço:

```
if object_id('fc_split', 'TF') is null
begin
  exec('create function fc_split() returns @resultado table(item varchar(max)) as begin return end');
end
go

alter function dbo.fc_split(@frase       varchar(max),
                            @delimitador varchar(max))
returns @resultado table(item      varchar(max),
                      sequencia integer)
begin
  declare @parte     varchar(max),
          @sequencia integer;

  set @sequencia = 0;

  while charindex(@delimitador, @frase, 0) <> 0
  begin
    set @parte = substring(@frase, 1, charindex(@delimitador, @frase, 0) - 1);
    set @frase = substring(@frase, charindex(@delimitador, @frase, 0) + len(replace(@delimitador, ' ', '.')), len(@frase));

    if len(@parte) > 0
    begin
      insert into @resultado(item, sequencia) values(@parte, @sequencia + 1);

      set @sequencia = @sequencia + 1;
    end;
  end;

  if len(@frase) > 0
  begin
    insert into @resultado(item, sequencia) values(@frase, @sequencia+ 1);
  end

  return;
end
go
```

Você só precisa fazer um `INTERSECT` com os resultados da divisão das duas frases, resultando na correção da sua função:

```
if object_id('splitSearchAddress', 'TF') is null
begin
  exec('create function splitSearchAddress() returns @resultado table(item varchar(max)) as begin return end');
end
go

alter function dbo.splitSearchAddress(@addressSearch varchar(max),
                                      @addressIn     varchar(max))
returns @returnList table(name nvarchar (500))
as
begin
  insert into @returnList(name)
  select item
    from fc_split(@addressSearch, ' ')
  intersect
  select item
    from fc_split(@addressIn, ' ');

  return
end
```

> [**Operador INTERSECT**](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/intersect.php)
>
> O operador `INTERSECT` é usado para retornar o resultado de 2 ou mais `SELECT`. No entrando só retornará as linhas que são selecionadas por todas as `queries` ou `data sets`. Se um registro existir em uma `query` e não em outra, ela será omitida do resultado.